Rust STM32 HID mouse not write report
I'm programming a stm32f103C8T6 (Blue pill) using Rust to configure as mouse device However, when I write the report, the mouse does not move and the usb device is not listed by lsusb command at any time.
I generated the project with this template:
cargo generate --git https://github.com/rust-embedded/cortex-m-quickstart
I configured the memory.x file and try the usb_bus example in crate stm32f1xx_hal
Whit this example everything works fine, the usb device is recognized and I can communicate with the board via the serial port.
The problem comes when I tried to configure it as a mouse I based my code in this examples

https://github.com/dlkj/usbd-human-interface-device/blob/main/examples/src/bin/mouse_wheel.rs
https://github.com/kndndrj/mouse/blob/master/firmware-rust/mouse-fw/src/main.rs
https://github.com/andy31415/rust_stm32f411_demos/blob/master/examples/usb_mouse.rs

The problem with these examples is that none of them are based on the stm32f1 board so their hal implementations are slightly different
My code looks like this:
fn main() {
    // boilerplate copied from usb_serial stm32f1xx_hal example
    let dp = pac::Peripherals::take().unwrap();

    let mut flash = dp.FLASH.constrain();
    let rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();

    let clocks = rcc
        .cfgr
        .use_hse(8.MHz())
        .sysclk(48.MHz())
        .pclk1(24.MHz())
        .freeze(&mut flash.acr);

    assert!(clocks.usbclk_valid());

    // Configure the on-board LED (PC13, green)
    let mut gpioc = dp.GPIOC.split();
    let mut led = gpioc.pc13.into_push_pull_output(&mut gpioc.crh);
    led.set_high(); // Turn off

    let mut gpioa = dp.GPIOA.split();

    // BluePill board has a pull-up resistor on the D+ line.
    // Pull the D+ pin down to send a RESET condition to the USB bus.
    // This forced reset is needed only for development, without it host
    // will not reset your device when you upload new firmware.
    let mut usb_dp = gpioa.pa12.into_push_pull_output(&mut gpioa.crh);
    usb_dp.set_low();
    hprintln!("USB reset");
    delay(clocks.sysclk().raw());
    hprintln!("USB reset fisnished");

    // and this code is based in the rest of the examples
    let usb = Peripheral {
        usb: dp.USB,
        pin_dm: gpioa.pa11.into_floating_input(&mut gpioa.crh),
        pin_dp: usb_dp.into_floating_input(&mut gpioa.crh),
        // pin_dp: usb_dp.into_floating_input(&mut gpioa.crh),
    };
    let usb_bus = UsbBus::new(usb);

    // let mut serial = SerialPort::new(&usb_bus);

    let mut mouse = UsbHidClassBuilder::new()
        .add_device(WheelMouseConfig::default())
        .build(&usb_bus);

    let mut usb_dev = UsbDeviceBuilder::new(&usb_bus, UsbVidPid(0x1209, 0x0001))
        .manufacturer("TEST")
        .product("TEST")
        .serial_number("TEST")
        .supports_remote_wakeup(false)
        .device_class(0x03) // HID
        .build();

    let mut report = WheelMouseReport::default();

    delay(clocks.sysclk().raw());
    hprintln!("USB device created");
    loop {
        if !usb_dev.poll(&mut [&mut mouse]) {
            led.set_high(); // Turn off
            continue;
        }

        match mouse.device().write_report(&report) {
            Ok(_) => {
                led.set_low(); // Turn on
                hprintln!("Ok")
            }

            Err(err) => {
                hprintln!("Error: {:?}", err);
            }
        };

        report = WheelMouseReport::default();
        report.x += 110;
        report.y += -100;
        report.buttons = 0x01;
    }
}

